# Java: is there any risk to depend on field initializing sequence?

Tags: java, initialization, field, sequence

I'm using default initializing with class fields like this. I suppose the fields will be initialized in sequence like this:

```
class NormalInit {
    int i = 3;
    LocalDate h = LocalDate.now();
    public int year = h.getYear(); // is it safe?
}
```

My question:

(1) Is my assumption on sequence correct (Is this guaranteed by java or jvm specification)?

(2) Is there any common failure/pitfall about this kind of initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be OK. According to java memory model and language specification statements are evaluated in a single thread from top to bottom.

Order of initialization blocks https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4

> > 4.Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception

This link is for happens-before explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5

> > If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

Technically assignment to `i` and `h` could be reordered but in your case it will not have any impact on the semantics of the program.

Answer (score 1):

`h` depends on `year`, JVM will not reorder those assignments.

but `i` has no dependency, so JVM can put it's init at any moment of constructing.